# 'The estimated weights for the factor scores are probably incorrect' in psych package

Tags: r

I am using `psych::fa.parallel(df,fa="both",n.iter=100,cor=c( "tet"))`,I can get the result but has something matter:
`The estimated weights for the factor scores are probably incorrect.  Try a different factor extraction method.`
It seemed to say `fm=minres` is not good method, but I tried other method still has this problem.
What cause it?